# Is there a compact view for notebooks in VS code? Cells waste too much empty space

Tags: visual-studio-code

In every zoom level, there is too much empty space between cells.
If there a way to reduce margins between cells? Basically to have a combat cell view.
See image below for an example: [EXAMPLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrRuc.png)